# How do I render a collection of models each with variable view and controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a collection of models in my Ember.js app, which I would like to render. The catch is that I want to be able to specify a specialized view and controller for each of the models.

The controller part seems to be easy: I would just wrap the array in an `ArrayController` and implement `itemController` method. The view part is where it gets tricky. I don't see an obvious idiomatic way of doing this.

The best way we came up with is the combination of `ArrayController` and `CollectionView` with an overridden `createChildView`. For instance:

```
createChildView: function(viewClass, attrs) {
    var viewInstance,
        widgetType = attrs.content.get('type');

    // lookup view, if found, use it, if not, pass empty view
    var viewDefined = this.container.lookup('view:' + widgetType);
    var createWidgetType = viewDefined ? widgetType : 'empty';

    // create view instance from widgetType name
    // it causes lookup in controller
    viewInstance = this._super(createWidgetType, attrs);
    // if `attrs.content` is controller (item of `ComponentsController`)
    // set it as controller of newly created view
    if(attrs.content.get('isController')) {
        viewInstance.set('controller', attrs.content);
    }
    return viewInstance;
}
```

This feels unnecessarily convoluted, I don't like that I have to connect the view with the controller manually like that. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `{{render}}` helper. It'll create a view and controller for each instance.

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{render "item" item}}
{{/each}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuwimu/2/edit?html,js,output

Render helper guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper

Additionally:

In your comment you mentioned you want different controller/view types for particular model types. This could be done like this:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#if item.typeX}}
    {{render "itemX" item}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if item.typeY}}
    {{render "itemY" item}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

or if you'd choose to go with components:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#if item.typeX}}
    {{component-x item=item}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if item.typeY}}
    {{component-y item=item}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish in more detail it’s hard to tell what the best solution is.

Comment: I agree with kalman that using a component is a more elegant solution and more inline with the direction ember is heading.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't quite cut it, as I want to have a different controller and view type for each of the models and the first argument to {{render}} seems like can't be a variable. If, for instance the name of my view/controller we're a "type" field on the model, then {{render item.type item}} will trigger an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component, which will act as controller and have a view associated with it:

```
App.XItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  controllerProperty: '!',
  tagName: 'li'
});
```

Then, you can just do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each model }}
      {{ x-item item=this }}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wehevixolu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It is inaccurate to say that a component will act as a controller. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html

Comment: @givanse Technically, you are correct. One is a component and the other is a controller. There *is* a tendency to move away from controllers though (https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) and especially in this case, at least to me, it seems more natural to use a component rather than a controller + view.